# Ubuntu One Mac Beta: How do I move the Ubuntu One folder?

Tags: directory

I've just installed the Ubuntu One Mac Beta client and it syncs a folder called `~/Ubuntu One`.

However, I don't want this folder in my home directory. How can I move it or rename it so that another folder is my only sync'ed folder? For example, if I don't want `~/Ubuntu One`, but I want a sync'ed folder called `~/Cloud/Ubuntu/One`?

Thanks.

David

Comment: I don't have Ubuntu One for Mac, but I did try it for W$. There you could basically choose any folder in the home directory to be synced.